# Remove file in bash with exclude file

Tags: linux, bash

I want to remove some file in a directory but '.gitignore' file , I try this command but get an error

```
[vagrant@lw2 lw2]$ find ./web/assets/* ! -name '.gitignore' | xargs rm -rf
find: `./web/assets/*': No such file or directory
```

I try again with "." character but I get another error :

```
[vagrant@lw2 lw2]$ find ./web/assets/. ! -name '.gitignore' | xargs rm -rf 
 rm: cannot remove directory: `./web/assets/.'
```

Please tell me what wrong with these command 
Thank you !

Comment: How is the error message unclear?  `find` returns the name of the current directory but it cannot be removed. With `rm -rf` you would remove any directory which includes a `.gitignore` file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove file by file in order to avoid deleting the whole directory and therefore to achieve not deleting the `.gitignore`

Try this:

```
find ./web/assets/* -type f ! -name '.gitignore' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: This leaves a mound of empty directories.

Comment: If you see what the question was, you could see that he asks for remove files within a directory, and not remove directories as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  Why would they then use `rm -rf`?  Anyway, in that case, the simple obvious fix of passing in `-type d` would easily avoid the error message, and a large number of others.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I get it now. Thanks

Comment: Your code should use `-type f` and not use `rm -rf` if you are attempting to fix the OP's incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for files):

```
[vagrant@lw2 lw2]$ find /full/path/to/directory/ -type f ! -iname ".gitignore" -exec rm -fv {} \;
```

or this (for directories):

```
[vagrant@lw2 lw2]$ find /full/path/to/directory/ -type d ! -iname ".gitignore" -exec rm -fv {} \;
```

NOTE: Its better to test the command first using temporary directories then run the main command.